# Eclipse doesn't see classes from a plug-in dependency

Tags: eclipse, netty

I want to use Netty in an Eclipse RCP application. After downloading [the latest jar](http://www.jboss.org/netty/downloads.html), I've added it to dependencies of my plug-in, but packages it provides aren't resolved in the editor. It's visible under "Plug-in dependencies" in the Package Explorer, as are all other dependencies (which work fine). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What compilation error do you get when you import classes from netty? How did you create a plug-in project from the netty jar file? Did you use the "Plug-in from Existing JAR Archives" wizard? Are the packages of netty that you'd like to use exported in the manifest of the plug-in project of netty?

Comment: 1. "The import org.jboss cannot be resolved". 2. The jar is already an OSGi bundle (otherwise it couldn't be added to plug-in dependencies at all, I believe). 3. Yes, they are.

Comment: Yes, the netty JAR files are OSGi bundle. But, how did you add them as the dependencies of your plug-in. Eclipse won't allow you add a bundle to the list of dependencies unless it's imported in the workspace. How did you import the netty bundle into your Eclipse workspace?

Comment: I have a special project in my workspace to keep downloaded jars so they can be conveniently added to other projects.

Comment: I copied the netty jar file into a project of my workspace. But, Eclipse didn't allow me to add it as a dependency of another plug-in. I'm not sure how you've set up the dependency on netty.

Comment: I used the "Plug-in from Existing JAR Archives" wizard to create an Eclipse plug-in project from the netty JAR file. Then, I created a new plug-in project to depend on my netty project. I was successfully able to use the classes in the netty project in my driver project. I suggest you to try to import the netty JAR file using the "Plug-in from Existing JAR Archive" wizard.